# English translation of Descartes's Notae in Programma Quoddam?

Tags: metaphysics, history-of-philosophy, descartes, translation

The SEP entry on Descartes (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-works/) mentions his work "Notae in Programma Quoddam." It is referred to as "Notes on a Program-also referred to as Comments on a Certain Broadsheet" in English according to the article.

Has this text ever been translated into English? Is it available online?

Answer (score 2):

This text itself can be viewed as scanned fascimile of the Latin at [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/ned-kbn-all-00003575-001/page/n10).

A French translation appeared in *Cheminer avec Descartes*, dir. Thibaut Gress, Paris, Classiques Garnier, 2018, p. 191-212 (According to http://caphi.univ-nantes.fr/spip.php?article235 )

More information on it English occurs in "The Cambridge Descartes Lexicon" ([see here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cambridge-descartes-lexicon/comments-on-a-certain-broadsheet/9B5CFA4846B131A16975B0D7A67D6431)).

There's a translation by John Cottingham [in another volume](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/philosophical-writings-of-descartes/comments-on-a-certain-broadsheet/CDA366CB46886BA725AE80767FDADAEE) into English.